# Precision/Margin of Error (in meters) of iPhone/iPad Locations, Precise Location Off vs. On?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, geolocation, gps

I am a mobile app developer developing a pair of iOS apps that use device location for search, and I’m trying to put constraints on the dimensions necessary for a cells in a quadtree-based location mapping system.  The minimum cell size should roughly coincide with the margin of error for an iPhone or iPad with “use precise location” turned *off*.

Yes, I realize this likely varies by iPhone and iPad model, so if you can answer this question, please let me know which model(s) the statistics are for.  I am interested in finding this information about models from the last 5 years or so.  And I’m mostly interested in the margin of error for when precise location is turned off.

Does anyone know or know where I can find data on the precision of iPhone/iPad locations (i.e. a margin of error, as a range, in meters), for both precise location turned on and precise location turned off?

Comment: So if you stand on a street corner, what does it give for your location with it on and off? practical research..

Comment: This will depend on whether you're in the middle of nowhere; in an urban environment; indoors or outdoors. Whether the device has a cell signal, how fast you're moving… The map will give an estimated 'circle of precision' when you access it. See also https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/238484/how-accurate-is-the-location-detection-on-the-iphones-find-my-iphone-app

Comment: @Allan I think you've linked to the wrong thing

Comment: Thanks @Ezekiel.    See [this question/answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/334226/119271)

Comment: I sure hope someone has some practical information or finds a write up on the web. This is actually something interesting to me - to figure of Apple is randomizing the error (which I would bet a small amount of money on) or it's somehow trackable via GPS and cell tower signal [Trilateration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trilateration).

Comment: @Tetsujin thanks for that link—I’ve seen some of those figures (which are a bit old), but since “use precise location” was introduced, it isn’t clear to me exactly how the accuracy is quantitatively impacted.  Does “use precise location” “ON” just use GPS with cellular to back it up, while “OFF” uses cellular only?  Also of note is this: https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/93746.  Basically, with certain models, some users have reported poor or variable/jumpy GPS accuracy, and it turns out the cellular assist was interfering, such that a SIM eject + reboot was necessary.

Comment: @Allan Thanks, I understand what data/technologies Apple devices use to calculate location, but I’m looking for more quantitative data, specifically concerning the “use precise location” feature, how that affects accuracy *quantitatively*.  Ne thing that would be helpful to know is how exactly the devices implement “use precise location” ON versus OFF, as in, does “ON” use all four of those technologies listed on your link, while “OFF” uses some subset—if so, what is that subset?

Comment: @bmike Thank you for your edits to the question, I really appreciate it.

Comment: An update, with some more recent stats than that 2009 3G study: https://www.pointr.tech/blog/5g-indoor-positioning.  This article from mobile location platform Pointr gives accuracies for modern cellular positioning without GPS as follows: 4G LTE (50m), 5G sub-6Ghz (20m), and 5G mmWave (*sub-meter*).  I should also note that it lists some interesting indoor positioning system stats at the bottom of the article, but for my purposes I am not really looking at IPS stats.

Answer (score 0):

From a programmer's perspective, disabling the "Precise Location" feature is actually known as "reducedAccuracy". When in this mode, the app developer should only expect 1 to 20 kilometer horizontal accuracy. In addition, location updates will be delayed - so location data can be quite old (i.e. 15-20 minutes delayed).

I see in the comments that there is speculation that Apple applies a randomised error to the actual, precise location. That is not really the case. Instead Apple has mapped the globe into a number of cells, and when in reducedAccuracy mode, iOS tells the app only the center of the cell that  the user is currently in.

The reason for this feature is that it has allowed Apple to create cells of varying size at locations around the world. This means that with reducedAccuracy an app would most likely be able to tell which (larger) city the user is currently in.

Had Apple just introduced a random 20 km error, or just mapped the globe into fixed sized cells, an app might mistake you for being in a completely different city.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @jksoegaard, this is exactly the kind of info I am looking for.  Is this data available in the Apple Developer docs somewhere?  When you say "1-20km" for accuracy, are you referring to the range in the size of cells that they are using to map the spherical (well, as modeled) surface of the earth?  Do you know which algorithm they use to accomplish this? Simple geohashing or quadtree-based? Do they use z-ordering or Hilbert Curve to represent 2D areas on the sphere as an ordered, 1D list of IDs? Do they use Google S2? Or is it just an arbitrary, proprietary mapping?

Comment: How would it matter to you which algorithm they use? - It is completely transparent to the developer. You can use any algorithm you want as an app developer for your own mapping purposes.

Comment: You wrote "Apple has mapped the globe into a number of cells".  Therefore I took that at face value to mean that it was not up to the developer, but instead a mapping created by Apple themselves.  If this is the case, as your answer implies, I am interested in what method they are using, because that would determine the dimensions of the cells (geohash = rectangular, while quadtree = square) and the way in which they are organized.

Comment: That mapping is created by Apple. The details of Apple's mapping is not exposed to the app. It does not mean that you cannot create your own mapping in your own app.

Comment: I am not interested in creating *my own* mapping, for any reason.  I am interested in what *Apple's* mapping is, because your original post made it seem that the accuracy of user device locations is based on Apple's mapping when in `reducedAccuracy` mode.  The entire point of this question is to get a sense of what this `reducedAccuracy` is, in concrete dimensions (or within some margin of error), and—if it changes geographically, as you've implied—how and where it does so.

Comment: I did not intend my original post to only "make it seem" that the accuracy of user device location is based on Apple's mapping when in reducedAccuracy mode". That is actually how it is. I have described in my original post what the concrete dimensions or margin of error is (1-20 km) and also that it does indeed change geographically. I cannot in my answer describe the globe in such a detail that you would know the exact mapping of all cities in the world, I'm sorry.

Comment: OK, that is understandable, but if it isn't too much to ask, I would still like to know: 1. where this figure of 1-20km came from originally (is this your observed/measured experience or in the documentation somewhere), and 2. if the 1-20km margin of error you mention is a direct byproduct of the way Apple maps the spherical surface of the earth—for example with Google S2, depending on the latitude, cell levels 13 to 9 represent approximately a margin of error of ~1 to ~20 km, respectively.

Comment: 1) Documented for app developers by Apple. 2) Yes, ofcourse the error is a direct byproduct of the way Apple maps the earth. That's directly what I wrote in my answer, and as I described in my answer, it is very intentional that it is built that way.